# Cython + Windows 8.1 + VS express 2013

Tags: python, windows, cython

So, that's another Windows + cython question... Cython does succeed in compiling some simple scripts (although not all), and gcc exits with an error code on most. I have configured `Setup.py` to use MingW32 as compiler from `Setup.cfg`. I also have MCVS express installed, but it seems that using it as compiler would require me to have the 2008 version, which cannot be found anymore. I read quite a lot about failure to cythonize on Windows, but I can't find the magic trick. It seems that any script containing `cdef` will fail to compile. Can someone please help?

### Config:

- Windows 8.1 (x64, of course)
- Python 2.7.6 32-bits
- Cython 0.20.2 precompiled for 32-bits windows
- Microsoft visual Studio express 2013

### Test Project:

- test.py
- setup.py
- setup.cfg

### Setup.cfg:

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

### Setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize


setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("test.py")
)
```

### test.py that works:

```
def say_hello_to(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name)
```

### test2.py that Fails (changing Setup.py accordingly):

```
def primes(int kmax):
cdef int n, k, i
cdef int p[1000]
result = []
if kmax > 1000:
    kmax = 1000
k = 0
n = 2
while k < kmax:
    i = 0
    while i < k and n % p[i] != 0:
        i = i + 1
    if i == k:
        p[k] = n
        k = k + 1
        result.append(n)
    n = n + 1
return result
```

### Mingw32 error Output:

```
PS C:\Users\Raoul\Desktop\cython_trys> python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling test2.py because it changed.
Cythonizing test2.py

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def primes(int kmax):
              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test2.py:1:15: Expected ')', found 'kmax'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize("test2.py")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 798, in cythonize
cythonize_one(*args[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 915, in cythonize_one
raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: test2.py
```

Comment: The error message is a "Permission denied" from the filesystem, not anything about the code. Any chance you built the first one, `import`ed it into a Python interactive interpreter or script, then, without quitting, tried to build the second one in the exact same path, thereby trying to overwrite the existing one that was still open and locked?

Comment: Is there a reason you're naming your Cython files .py instead of .pyx? Also, if that's really your code, there's an obvious `IndentationError`; is the problem just that Cython is giving you the wrong error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new problem is just that you've named your file `test2.py` instead of `test2.pyx`.

If you do things manually, Cython doesn't care what you call the file—if you tell it to compile some code as Cython code, it'll compile it.

But when you use the `cythonize` function to create your `ext_modules`, it does so by guessing the file types based on extension: `.py` means pure-Python code, `.pyx` means Cython code. So, it's trying to compile your code as pure Python, and of course that `int kmax` is not a valid parameter in Python. (And the reason you get errors on `cdef` in other tests is the same, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive this is the problem, but it's at least likely:

The error message is:

```
cannot open output file C:\Users\Raoul\Desktop\cython_trys\test.pyd: Permission denied
```

This is probably not because you don't have permission to create a new file in `cython_trys`, but because there's already a file named `test.pyd` that's opened for exclusive access and therefore locked, so attempting to overwrite it with a new file (as `gcc` is trying to do) will fail.

Why might it be open and locked?

Well, if you did an `import test` in an interactive Python session, or a script, to test out the first `test.py` that worked, and you've left it running, it still has `test.pyd` open. The easiest fix is to just quit that Python session or script.

Or, instead of reusing the same file, you could just create a new file with a different name.

---

The reason tutorials written by Unix people don't mention this is that on Unix, a file doesn't get deleted until you remove the last link to it in the filesystem *and* close the last file handle to it in any process. So, you can `rm` a file, or write a new file over it, and anyone who had it open still has it open and can read and write it just fine. But on Windows, as soon as the last filesystem link goes away, the file can be deleted, even if someone else has a handle to it. Which would obviously be disastrous. So Windows uses exclusive access locks all over the place to prevent you from doing things like that.

Comment: It seems that part of my Problems came from that (yes, I can be very stupid...), however a compiling error persists (it seems that any script that contains `cdef` produces that error), please see updated question. BTW the question changed, so I will accept your answer if no one solves this completely.

Comment: @Raoul: Instead of editing a question to a completely different question, it's better to just create a new question (and put links from each one to the other, if appropriate). From your point of view, you get more rep that way; from the good-of-the-site point of view, it means anyone with your original problem can find it in a search, instead of finding a completely different problem unrelated to what he searched for.

Comment: Oooooooook, so I think I'll go hide in a corner, now... The problem was that I was naming my Input files `.py` instead of `.pyx`. For whatever reason, I thought it was related to pyrex... And thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Raoul: It _is_ related to Pyrex. Cython is basically a successor to Pyrex, and it uses the same extensions roughly the same way.

Comment: @Raoul: Also, those simple errors are exactly the kind everyone always needs help on. Your brain doesn't notice things that are so trivial and obvious, _especially_ in your own code…